# Product of smooth manifolds with smooth manifold with boundary is smooth manifold with boundary, solution verification.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

> Suppose $M_1, \dots,M_k$ are smooth manifolds and $N$ smooth manifold with boundary.
> Then $M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \times N$ is a smooth manifold with boundary and $\partial (M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \times N)=M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \times \partial N$.

Attempted solution.

I will use induction to prove the result.
Let $k=1$ and $(x,y) \in M_1 \times N$. Then there exists chart $(U, \phi )$ at $x$ on the Atlas of $M_1$ and chart $(V,\psi )$ at $y$ on the Atlas of $N$. $U \times V$ is a neighborhood of $(x,y)$ (with the product topology) and $\phi \times \psi$ is a homeomorphism from $U \times V$ to $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathcal{H}^m$. Notice that $\mathcal{H}^{n+m} =\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathcal{H}^m$. Hence $M_1 \times N$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathcal{H}^{n+m}$, i.e. is a manifold with boundary.

Now if $(x,y) \in \partial ( M_1 \times N)$, then $\phi_1 \times \psi (x,y)$ is a boundary point of $\mathcal{H}^{n+m}$. Notice that $\partial (\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathcal{H}^m)=\partial (\mathcal{H}^{n+m}) =\mathbb{R}^n \times \partial \mathcal{H}^m$, hence $\phi_1 \times \psi (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \partial \mathcal{H}^m$ and so $(x,y) \in M_1 \times \partial N$.

Now if $(x,y) \in M_1 \times \partial N$, then $\psi (y)$ is a boundary point of $\mathcal{H}^m$, therefore $\phi_1 \times \psi (x,y)$ is a boundary point of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathcal{H}^m$ hence $(x,y) \in \partial (M \times N)$.

Finally, induction will give the required result.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Welcome. What is the meaning of $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: This is the upper half space.

Comment: Seems like most of it is there! Since manifolds are topological spaces, the product is Cartesian, together with the corresponding topology like you said (since this is a finite product, we don't have to worry about Box vs. Tychonoff topologies). For the three manifold axioms, you got locally Euclidean and hinted at the construction of the smooth atlas. You should mention why the Hausdorff and Second Countable axioms hold. Lastly, I would maybe include why charts preserve boundary points in both directions (homeo = bi-continuous & bijective) as these are kind of just stated.